# Set some values to NULL if.. other values are null

Tags: mysql

I have this medium-sized query and I am having some problems getting certain fields.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  enc.id, enc.cus_id, enc.createdon, enc.status, 
  enc.segment, enc.currentstep, enc.groupid, enc.fdprotocol, 
  enc_task.linkfile, cus.fname, cus.lname, login.first_name, 
  login.last_name, login.username, login.user_code, fp.protocol 
FROM
  mob_encounters_task enc_task, mob_encounters enc, 
  mob_customer cus, mob_login login, mob_protocol_type fp 
WHERE 
  enc.id=enc_task.encounterid 
AND 
  cus.id=enc_task.cus_id 
AND 
  login.id=enc.createdby 
GROUP BY enc.id
```

**fp.protocol** is a string, and on the table **fp** there are up to 5 or 6 "protocols".

what I wanted to do is if **enc.fdprotocol** is empty then **fp.protocol** should be empty, otherwise get the **fp.protocol** associated to the **fp.id**= **enc.fdprotocol**

Please let me know if this sounds confusing, I have been stuck on this for some time

Comment: You have a whole bunch of tables joined here, but only a joining condition between two of them.  How are all these tables related? (what you're asking for is a LEFT JOIN, but it is hard to find where to put it and what is actually necessary here with all these tables()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that using the actual JOIN syntax makes queries much more readable and maintainable. In this case you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` and you have to change your syntax for that:

```
SELECT enc.id, enc.cus_id, enc.createdon, enc.status, enc.segment, 
enc.currentstep, enc.groupid, enc.fdprotocol, enc_task.linkfile, cus.fname, 
cus.lname, login.first_name, login.last_name, login.username, login.user_code, 
fp.protocol 
    FROM mob_encounters_task enc_task
    JOIN mob_encounters enc ON enc.id=enc_task.encounterid
    JOIN mob_customer cus ON cus.id=enc_task.cus_id
    JOIN mob_login login ON login.id=enc.createdby 
    LEFT JOIN mob_protocol_type fp ON fp.id = enc.fdprotocol
```

Also I don't believe you need `DISTINCT`

Comment: Thank you! Finally! Almost ran out of hairs to pull. The database layout is a mess, but unfortunately redesign it now is not an option.

I had to remove the commas on the joins, but everything else works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: oops ... yeah I copied and pasted from your original and forgot to get rid of the commas. Glad I could help.